# Include operator could not be bound in Entity Framework Core with Identity DB

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, eager-loading, ef-database-first

I am writing a application using ASP.Net Core + EF Core + Identity 2.0 + DB First + Repository Pattern

From DB first I am scaffolding an existing database (with Identity tables) and do some clean up steps in Context to make it work for Identity.

1. Inherit it from IdentityDbContext instead of DbContext

   ```
   public partial class SampleDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
   ```
2. Remove "OnConfiguring" method override
3. Add a new constructor for the SampleDbContext class `public SampleDbContext (DbContextOptions<SampleDbContext> options):base(options){}`
4. Remove all DbSet configuration for EF Core Identity tables such as,
   AspNetRoleClaims
   AspNetRoles
   AspNetUserClaims
   AspNetUserLogins
   AspNetUserRoles
   AspNetUserTokens
   AspNetUsers
5. In "OnModelCreating" override function add below line  `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`
6. Remove all modelBuilder.Entity configs for all EF Core Identity tables mentioned above.
7. Add below line in OnModelCreating() function,

   `modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>().HasKey(i => i.LoginProvider);
    modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>().HasKey(i => i.ProviderKey);
    modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRoles>().HasKey(i => i.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRoles>().HasKey(i => i.RoleId);
    modelBuilder.Ignore<AspNetRoleClaims>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<AspNetRoles>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<AspNetUserClaims>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<AspNetUserLogins>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<AspNetUserRoles>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<AspNetUsers>();`

So far all works fine. Able to read/write data to DB.

Now, attempting to read a table data which has a foreign key reference to one of Identity tables (ASPNetUsers) as follows,

```
var dbEntries = await _addressRepository.GetAllAsync(x => x.CreatedBy);
```

where CreatedBy is foreign key reference to "Id" columns in AspNetUsers table passed as include property to my repository.

Now the above `GetAll()` command throws exception,

```
InvalidOperationException: The expression '[x].CreatedBy' passed to the Include operator could not be bound.
```

Could any one help me to resolve this issue? I spent over a day to find solution online, but nothing got.

Additional Note: All are working fine if I refer my own tables in Include objects. Issue only with Identity tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this ...  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2048 ... might be helpful to you.

Comment: You have issues with Identity tables because of all your `Ignore` calls in the fluent configuration. With `Ignore` you are telling EF that these classes are **not** entities, hence the reference/collection properties pointing to them will not be treated as navigation properties (relationship).

Comment: @IvanStoev: You are correct. I can understand the `Ignore` causing the issue, but if I omit `Ignore<T>` for Identity tables it throws another exception,
`InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'AspNetUsers' in schema '' for entity 'IdentityUser' since it is being used for another entity.`
Because of DB First with Identity tables we used `Ignore<T>`. If there is any other option to avoid `Ignore<T>` while doing DB First with Identity tables?
Please help.

Comment: @MuqeetKhan I already tried this solution before opening this question, but it didn't help. :(

Comment: @IvanStoev is right. The solution of removing all dbsets and ignore identity entities is incorrect here. Your model is incomplete, hence you cannot use the include. Perhaps ask/look for how to use Identity with Db First.